# How to add Binance Smart Chain to Chain List of Safe Web?

Tags: gnosis-safe

i created my own instance of [Safe Wallet Web](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-wallet-web) and for now i have only 4 networks in network selector
[image: Network selector in Safe Wallet Web]

Can you please advise on how to modify the network list? How to add or remove networks? e.g i need to add Binance Smart Chain, and remove all test networks

Thank you in advance